# C# fast chart approximate comparison algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, charts

I have 2 series of values. By showing them in a chart, they are quite similar (they have the same behavior, when one grows, the other one grows, when one has small values, the other has small values; BUT: It may occur that one is growing and the other is descending). Important is that they do not have strictly the same values. I am interested in the general behavior of these 2 charts.

Right now, I am comparing them by doing the average on both graphs, and building 2 bool arrays. when a value is above the average, the corresponding value in bool[] is true, otherwise false. Then I compare these 2 bool[], by using Hamming distance.
This algorithm works, but not as good as I wished it would work. (It doesn't detect all matches between charts).

Does anyone have an idea of a better algorithm for performing this operation?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the kind of statement you expect from the number that you are calculating.

Comment: What I am achieving is this: index an mp3. listen the mp3 and record it using a microphone. the original mp3 has some data, and the recorded mp3 has other data. now i want to compare the data from the original mp3 with the data got from the recorder one (their graphs are similar, but not exactly the same - as stated above). The result: "the listened-recorded mp3 is from the original mp3 x" => something like the Shazam service.

Comment: Then I would go for the `Correlation Coefficient`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way of calculating a distance between two lists of numbers is to calculate the sum of the squares of the differences between them. This used quite often in statistics.

```
double sum = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    double diff = a[i] - b[i];
    sum += diff*diff;
}
```

But the fundamental question is, what kind of statement you are expecting from such an analysis.

---

Another possibility is to calculate the [Correlation Coefficient](http://mathbits.com/mathbits/tisection/statistics2/correlation.htm) between the two series. A coefficient of `+1` means that the two series fit 100%, `0` means that there is no apparent relation between the two series and `-1` means that they are the pure opposite of each other.

Comment: This answer seems to be the most complete, so I will set it as the answer for my  question. The problem is that I need a very fast algorithm. By using one of these algo, the performance will decrease (For a 200 point chart, I will have to use this algorithm for about 2800 * 4500 times. Curently, I am doing it in about 1 minute on a 4 core comp). Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

For a better performance I would use a "Zero mean test". It consists in checking if the average value of two samples are significally different using confident intervals.

Basically, it consists in:

1. Calculate the difference of all points of the charts
2. Calculate the mean and standard error of those differences (needed for the next point)
3. Calculate the confidence interval for a determined confidence (95%, 99%, ..., depends on the precision you want)

If that interval contains the value 0, the charts are not different.

Problem with this approach is that you will need a statistics library to calculate the interval, so I´m not sure if it fits in your problem

Answer (score 0):

right now you are only distinguishing between 2 states greater than or less than & equal.

i would use either 1, 0 -1 or create an enum to represent greater, same, less. this way you can distinguish between all three states.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of that, but I would never have equal. The chances for that are very very small.